# GEE | How to fix Error: Error in map(ID=0): Image.date: Image '0' does not have a 'system:time_start' property. (Error code: 3)

Tags: extract, libgee

I'm totally new to GEE. I got stuck now.

I'm trying to use geometry(contains a list of points) to extract daily GPM data from gee and then export to a csv file for analysis, the error is "Error: Error in map(ID=0): Image.date: Image '0' does not have a 'system:time_start' property. (Error code: 3)", can any one show me the road to fix that?

Here's the link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/de89de006915811d55669d4978a7c87a

Thanks a lot.

I tried to find all gpm images in one day and composite all of them as a daily image, and then using geometry to extract the daily image in time series. But after running a seconds, error occurs, can anyone help me with that?

Comment: fided by return dailyImage.set('system:time_start', start.millis()); to the daily var